# executeUpdate() only giving return value as 1

Tags: java, database

i have earlier asked the same ques , didnt get the answer 
i am updating a row in database from front end but i always get return value as 1
whether or not query is updating , i intentionally try to insert a wrong value or try to violate a constraint , i get exception at backend but the return value is always 1

java code :

```
 public int editportal(String env,String region,String url,String user,String rnode,String password,int envid,String attuid) throws Exception
   {
    int Affected=0; 
    log.debug("[Editconsole Method Call]");

     try {
      Connection con = db.getConnection();
      String editquery = "update ENV_MOTS_DETAILS set " +
            "ENV_NAME= ? , CONSOLE_URL= ? , REMOTE_NODE= ? , CONSOLE_TO_LOGON=? , " +
            "REGION=? , DELETE_FLAG='Y' , ADMIN_PWD=? , " +
            "COMPONENT='' , COMMENTS='' , LAST_UPDATED_BY=?, " +
            "LAST_UPDATED_ON=to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHERE ENV_ID = ?";

      log.info("[Editconsole Method Call Query]"+editquery);

      PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(editquery);

      ps1.setString(1,env);
      ps1.setString(2,url);
      ps1.setString(3,rnode);
      ps1.setString(4,user);
      ps1.setString(5,region);
      ps1.setString(6,password);
      ps1.setString(7,attuid);
      ps1.setInt(8,envid);

     Affected = ps1.executeUpdate();

     log.info("Statement affected " + Affected + " rows");
     ps1.close();
     con.close();

    } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
        log.fatal("[SQL Exception in Edit Server Details]"+e.getMessage());
        throw e;

      }
    return Affected;      
 }
```

stack trace when i intentionally try to get an error or return value as 0

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "INFRAJEWL"."ENV_MOTS_DETAILS"."ADMIN_PWD" (actual: 147, maximum: 50)

```
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:573)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1891)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:1093)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:2047)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:1940)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2709)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:589)
    at com.amdocs.infraportal.query.GetServerInfoDao.editportal(GetServerInfoDao.java:202)
    at com.amdocs.infraportal.servlets.Edit.doPost(Edit.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
```

Comment: if your **WHERE ENV_ID = ?** here  ENV_ID is unique in your DB so it will return 1 try if this value have two or more

Comment: `executeUpdate()` should return 0 if it is not updating anything in the DB.

Comment: Could you share an example of trying to insert with incorrect values ? What's the stacktrace ? Because if your `executeUpdate()` fails, I doubt it return something...

Comment: Unrelated, but: `to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` makes no sense whatsoever. `sysdate` **is** a date. Your expression is converting a `DATE` value to a `VARCHAR` value, just to convert that back to a `DATE` value (which it was to begin with)

Comment: @RahulBhawar  ..yes it is happening like this only ..it returns 0 only in case of primary key error and not for any other error

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the documentation for [executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()). It's return value should not be used to determine whether an update was successful or not.

Comment: so what should i do in this case ... bugging me a lot .. i am displaying a message at frontend on the basis of this return value

Comment: If you want the updated count, you can specify useAffectedRows=true as a [non-standard URL option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). More information is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140706054128/http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/168-how-to-obtain-the-number-of-rows-affected-by-a-statement-in-mysql).

Comment: it is giving 0 when exception but -1 when row is updated

Comment: Please read the documentation on [getUpdateCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount%28%29). It is returning -1 likely because the current result is a ResultSet.

Answer (score 1):

`executeUpdate()` method of `PreparedStatement` always returns either

- the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or
- 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

reference from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Comment: Yes thats what I mentioned in answer, either it returns the count of rows that affected with the query or returns `0`. check reference please.

Comment: Why this answer is downvoted. The answer is correct and mentioned reference documentation link also.